# How find this $AD= ?$

Tags: geometry

If $\angle A+\angle C=\pi,\angle B+\angle D=\dfrac{\pi}{2}$,and
$AB=\sqrt{18},CD=1,BC=\sqrt{32}$

Find $AD=?$

[image]

this problem from a test,I think this have nice solution,Thank you.
I have this solution

let$ OA=x,OD=y$,then we have
$$\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{2}}+\dfrac{y}{\sqrt{2}}+\sqrt{18-\dfrac{x^2}{2}}-\sqrt{1-\dfrac{y^2}{2}}=\sqrt{32}$$
and $\Delta ABA'∽\Delta DD'C$,then we have
$$3\sqrt{2}=\dfrac{AB}{CD}=\dfrac{AA'}{DD'}=\dfrac{OA}{OD}=\dfrac{x}{y}$$

Then find
$x+y=$
[image]
But I think problem have some nice solution, and we can't use sine or co-sine rule. Thank you

Comment: Did you try something like:

Label intersection of $AD$ and $BC$ as $O$ and assign $OD$ as $y$. It is clear that $$AOB=DOC=\frac{\pi}{4}$$
$$\frac{3\sqrt{2}}{\sin45}=\frac{4\sqrt{2}-x}{\sin A}=\frac{AD-y}{\sin B}$$
and 
$$\frac{1}{\sin45}=\frac{x}{\cos B}=\frac{y}{\sin A}.$$

Comment: sorry,I Forget this is the second day of test questions, can't use sine theorem

Comment: yes, I edit,Thank you Julien

Comment: YES,@julien,this problem can't use sine law and cosine law.

Comment: Then maybe you should add that information to the body of your question.

Comment: On the Stack Exchange network, it is better to *answer your own question* using a separate answer post, and not edit the question to include the answer. I suggest you move your answer to an answer post and then change the question post back to only include the question.